# Why does typescript suggest object may be undefined, even after explicitly checking it's not defined

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

#### Minimal Reproducable Example

```
type Keys = "FOO" | "BAR";

type ThingType = {
    category: Keys,
    thingName: string;
}

type CategorisedThings = Partial<Record<Keys, string[]>>
type ListedThings = ThingType[]

const categorizeFunction = (listedThings: ListedThings) => {
    const result: CategorisedThings = {}
    for (const thing of listedThings) {
        if (result[thing.category] !== undefined) {             // line 14
            result[thing.category].push(thing.thingName)       // line 15
        } else {
            result[thing.category] = [thing.thingName]
        }
    }
}
```

In the example above, typescript produces the error `Object is possibly 'undefined'.` on line 15:

```
            result[thing.category].push(thing.thingName)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

#### My Question

I would like to understand why typescript suggests that this might be undefined when in the previous line, I have explicitly checked that the thing isn't undefined.

There are a few ways I am able to work around the problem. For example I could do this:

```
result[thing.category]?.push(thing.thingName)
```

The error goes away, but I'm just checking the same thing (not quite, but more or less) twice.

I have tried several approaches in line 14, but they all give the same error.

Comment: I think it's just a warning which can be suppessed and it doesnt concern the flow and previous logic.
the ? covers the undefined object check, and it wont throw a fatal error and continues to execute the code. You can just do "result[thing.category]?.push(thing.thingName)" and it'll push if the array exists

Comment: It’s [ms/TS#10530](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530). TS currently only tracks the *type* of the key (`Keys` in your case) and not its *identity* (`thing.category`) so it can’t tell the difference between your code and something like `if (result[key1]) result[key2].push`. Does that fully address the question? If so I’ll write up an answer explaining (or find an appropriate dupe target). If not what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks @jcalz. Yes, that answers the question. It's a bit frustrating but it makes sense. Thankyou. If you write up an answer I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known longstanding TypeScript issue being tracked at [microsoft/TypeScript#10530](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530).  TypeScript can only [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) the apparent type of a [property access expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) like `obj[key]` if the property's key is of a single [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) like `"foo"`.  If the key type is something else, like `string`, a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type, or a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of literals, it won't work.  That's because currently only the *type* of the key is tracked, and not its *identity*.  The compiler can't tell the difference between  `if (test(obj[key])) process(obj[key])` and `if (test(obj[key1])) process(obj[key2])` if `key`, `key1`, and `key2` are all of the same type.  If that type is a single literal type like `"foo"` then it's fine to do some narrowing, because we know that `obj[key1]` and `obj[key2]` refer to exactly the same property.  But if that type is something else, then it's possible you're testing one property and then processing another unrelated one.

In your example code, the key is `thing.category`, whose type is `Keys`, a union of string literals `"FOO"` and `"BAR"`.  So the compiler doesn't know if the expression `result[thing.category]` will refer the same thing every time it appears (I suppose it's technically possible for that to be false, if you wrote `thing.category = "BAR"` somewhere between the test and the processing... but even if you saved `thing.category` to a new `const key = thing.category` it would be equally unsure about `result[key]`).  So it won't narrow for you.

Maybe someday this will be improved by tracking the *identity* of the key in addition to the type (and possibly only if the key is a `const` or somehow known not to have been modified), but until and unless that happens you need to work around it.

---

The most common workaround is to save the property to a new variable and write your code with that variable instead, like `const v = result[key.category]` and then you'd be writing `if (v) v.push(⋯)`, but in this case  you're also trying to *set* `result[key.category]` which you can't do through another variable.

So instead I'd probably advise you to use the [nullish coalescing assignment (`??=`) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment) to initialize `result[thing.category]` if necessary and then use the known-non-nullish result:

```
const categorizeFunction = (listedThings: ListedThings) => {
  const result: CategorisedThings = {}
  for (const thing of listedThings) {
    (result[thing.category] ??= []).push(thing.thingName)
  }
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcoF4oCIBiB5LaoB90AhAQQCU0BuAKGtEigBUALASwDsBzR8aVAb2pQoAYwCGwCJwD2AJxAAuWPAQAaIVGBsuAOTEBbCEoTBZHTjQC+tetADCEqXNYIIAExbmkqAApjZwKxiADYAPGQQInJuoXCIqlAmZlwA2gC6AHwZdLxQADIukh7anN5MJTyQ6bRR7CaijjJmAF4QGACu7CKB0uwoUAAUwYXunlwISgUmoyUIAJQoGVCCwrX1shAI7cHASg6STS4zXv381sIAZnKDa8CaJVDSF1DD08VeCyvCgxtbOylacwAOnEBzkIDSUAA-FDUOk5kCwO0EMwBoCuED0Zw9IY5hpzlAAPSE0S9BDSYIQIHBaScAa-bbAPHWai3KAAN36oKcLTanW6rF6AxS-AaYPkSkwODQCSxOKM6DEeEsCVF3KaimI5Bl93M8slzWVaTxQA)